# Printer showing as Idle when queried via Win32_Printer, depsite being Offline

Tags: c#, winapi, printing

I am looking to get the status of a particular printer by querying Win32_Printer using a ManagementObjectSearcher. My code is below:

```
using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher($"SELECT * FROM Win32_Printer WHERE Name LIKE '{printerName}'"))
{
    using (ManagementObjectCollection coll = searcher.Get())
    {
        foreach (ManagementObject printer in coll)
        {
            var status = printer.Properties["PrinterStatus"].Value.ToString();
            var extendedPrinterStatus = printer.Properties["ExtendedPrinterStatus"].Value.ToString();
            var printerState = printer.Properties["PrinterState"].Value.ToString();

            Console.WriteLine(status); // 3 (Idle)
            Console.WriteLine(printerState); // 0 (Idle)
            Console.WriteLine(extendedPrinterStatus); // 2 (Unknown)

            return status == "3";
        }
    }
}
```

Regardless of whether or not the printer is connected, the values of *PrinterStatus*, *ExtendedPrinterStatus* and *PrinterState* remain the same. When the printer is disconnected, it shows as Offline under *Printers and Scanners* in Windows.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? I can't figure it out!

Thanks

Comment: Nothing.  You are only getting what the Print Driver supports.  There may be a new version of the print driver.  When the printer goes off line it is writing the status but not while printing.

Comment: @jdweng Thanks, do you know how the Windows *Printers & Scanners* window is able to accurately say whether or not the printer is connected?

Comment: Not for sure.  When you have an Ethernet TCP connection you can implement a Keep-Alive where printer would send a message periodically to server and when the message stop the server can report the printer off line.  Not sure if this is how your printer works.

Comment: It's USB, Windows has no problem telling me when it is/isn't connected, but querying Win32_Printer gives me an incorrect status

Comment: Check Device Manager to see if you are using the Vendors USB Driver.  The standard Microsoft USB driver will not give same status as vendors driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Regardless of whether or not the printer is connected, the values of PrinterStatus, ExtendedPrinterStatus and PrinterState remain the same.*

> If you are retrieving PrinterStatus = 3 or PrinterState = 0, the
> printer driver may not be feeding accurate information into WMI. WMI
> retrieves the printer information from the spoolsv.exe process. It is
> possible the printer driver does not report its status to the spooler.
> In this case, Win32_Printer reports the printer as Idle.

Refer: [Win32_Printer class Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-printer?redirectedfrom=MSDN#remarks)

*do you know how the Windows Printers & Scanners window is able to accurately say whether or not the printer is connected?*

If you want to [determine the state of a physical printer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows/win32/printer-print-job-status#determine-the-state-of-a-physical-printer),

> There is one fundamental premise that must be true to determine the
> state of a physical printer: the Spooler must be attempting to send a
> print job to the physical printer. This is the only time the state of
> the printer is reported by the port monitor. In addition, the most
> meaningful information may be reported in the status members of a
> JOB_INFO structure for that particular print job because some port
> monitor will have set these values directly.
>
> The JOB_INFO structures contain a Status member and a pStatus member.
> Both members contain status information of a print job reported by the
> port monitor.

[Sample Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows/win32/printer-print-job-status#sample-code)

BTW, in Win32_Printer class, `PrinterState` is Deprecated.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I ended up querying the list of connected USB devices and looking for the printer that way, will check out the sample code

Comment: @JMK [EnumPrinters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/printdocs/enumprinters)  with `PRINTER_ENUM_LOCAL` parameters can list local printers.

Comment: @JMK Hi, if the answer is useful to you, don't forget to accept it :)